# I am struggling with python-html . I know the class of a certain header. I need the info from the generic <a href... in this h1

Tags: python, html, urllib2

So, I have this:

```
<h1 class='entry-title'>
    <a href='http://theurlthatvariesinlengthbasedonwhenirequesthehtml'>theTitleIneedthatvariesinlength</a>
</h1>
```

How can I retrieve the URL (it is not always the same) and the title (also not always the same)?

Comment: ...use an HTML parser?

Answer (score 0):

Parse it with an **HTML parser**, e.g. with [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) it would be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = "your HTML here"  # data can be the result of urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
link = soup.select("h1.entry-title > a")[0]

print link.get("href")
print link.get_text()
```

where `h1.entry-title > a` is a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) matching an `a` element directly under `h1` element with `class="entry-title"`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just working with strings, you can

```
>>> s = '''<h1 class='entry-title'>
...     <a href='http://theurlthatvariesinlengthbasedonwhenirequesthehtml'>theTitleIneedthatvariesinlength</a>
... </h1>'''
>>> s.split('>')[1].strip().split('=')[1].strip("'")
'http://theurlthatvariesinlengthbasedonwhenirequesthehtml'
>>> s.split('>')[2][:-3]
'theTitleIneedthatvariesinlength'
```

There are other (and better) options for parsing HTML though.